# Searching multiple attributes for one value

Tags: java, android, xpath

I am using this xpath expression

```
String expr = String.format("//a/b/c[@name1='%s']", name);
```

I am making an android app that searches a xml document for a name.  I want it to search through both attributes name1 and name2 listed in the xml.  As the expression is now, it searches name1 but if the name does not appear it force closes my app.  If it is there it works as I planned.  How can I get it to not only search both attribute values but if the name does not appear make sure the app does not force close?

Thanks

Ok figured the xpath part out, im just having it search all of the values

```
[@* = '%s']
```

But can anyone help me with the issue if the name does not appear in the xml?  To return a response "the name is not valid"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to surround your search with a try-catch block:

```
try {
  // Do your search here
}
catch (Exception e) {
  // Handle the situation where the name was not found here
}
```